# On Copying Garbage

Tags: c, arrays, standards, c11

A couple of days ago I had a small discussion here about the copying of, let's call it *garbage* because that's what is actually is, from one array to another and if that is acceptable in standard C (ISO/IEC 9899-2011) or not.

Wrapped in some example-code for clarity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

/*
    ?  = any byte with ('?' != '?' || '?' == '?'), that is: '?' may or may not be equal to '?'.
         tl;dr: just random garbage
   'x' = a one byte large (not necessary ASCII-encoded) known and defined character.
         tl;dr: neither random nor garbage
*/

int main(){
  // array = [?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
  char array[ARRAY_SIZE];
  // copy =  [?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
  char copy[ARRAY_SIZE];
  int i;

  // fill a part of "array" with a NUL terminated string
  // "part" is not necessary half+1 of it, the only condition is: #part < ARRAY_SIZE
  // such that we have at least one byte of garbage
  for(i = 0;i < ARRAY_SIZE/2;i++){
    // casting "i" is a bit "holier than the pope", admitted
    array[i] = (char)i + '0';
  }
  array[i] = '\0';
  // array = ['0','1','2','3','4','\0',?,?,?,?]

  // "use" the array "array"
  printf("array = %s\n",array);

  // copy all of the elements of "array" to "copy" including
  // the garbage at the end
  for(i = 0;i < ARRAY_SIZE;i++){
    copy[i] = array[i];
  }
  // copy = ['0','1','2','3','4','\0',?,?,?,?]

  // "use" the array "copy"
  printf("copy =  %s\n",copy);

  // no further use of either "array" or "copy".
  // obvious at the end of main() but meant generally, of course
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The paragraph in the standard that defines those kid of arrays is in the list of derived types:

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> *20* Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and
>   function types, as  follows:
>
> - An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set
>     of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.
>     The element type shall be complete whenever the array type is specified.
>     Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number of
>     elements in the array. An array type is said to be derived from its
>     element type, and if its element type is *T*, the array type is sometimes
>     called "array of *T*". The construction of an array type from an element
>     type is called  "array type derivation".

My question is: does "nonempty set" just mean that the `n` (where `n` stands in for an integer literal; it has nothing to do with VLAs) in the declaration `T a[n]` must be greater than zero?

For those of you who need a practical reason: in the realtime area a well defined number of operations is preferred over an unknown amount. It is also slower a large part of the times (assuming a random distribution of the input) because of the necessary measurement and this overhead matters a lot in the embeded area. Every saved nano-amperehour counts when the battery needs to keep enough juice to run it for a couple of years.

Comment: Reading uninitialized data is always undefined behavior. If the copying loop didn't read the uninitialized data (i.e. it checked for the terminator or the length and stopped there) then your program would be well defined.

Comment: Yes. It's just standardese. You can't declare a buffer of size 0, and the standard describes that as an "array". However you can pass N =0 and a pointer without any problems, so of course we can have empty arrays using the term in its proper sense. malloc(0) is also a bit dicey.

Comment: Technically Joachim is right. However your embedded system will not have trap representations and you can confidently copy garbage as non-char types with the expected effect.

Comment: Assembler used to have the directive: **assume nothing**. On second thought, assembler was right. Uninitialised == uninitialised. Deal with it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm pretty sure it can only be UB on systems with trap representations. The standard term is indeterminate value, which could either be an unspecified value or a trap representation. If it is an unspecified value, it is harmless. Some special cases of UB like reading an uninitialized variable during lvalue conversion exist, but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: I guess we're assuming that `ARRAY_SIZE/2` is small enough so that `(char)i + '0'` does not exceed `CHAR_MAX`

Comment: Please clarify: Your question starts off as if you are going to ask whether copying uninitialized bytes is undefined behaviour, but then the only actual question is "what does 'nonempty set'" mean?"   (which was answered by Mat).   Are you actually intending to ask about whether your code invokes UB, or was that just background context?

Comment: @M.M it all goes together, the only background given is the last paragraph about the embedded stuff to also lure the people in who hate purely theoretical questions.

Comment: I'm still not clear whether you want an answer to the question "does my code invoke UB?"  . If so, please edit the question to clearly include that as a question.

Comment: @M.M *all* means *all*, so if you have an answer to "does my code invoke UB?" *and* can give chapter and verse (I couldn't find anything, not even that, hence I asked) go along and answer. I'm pretty gracious with my upvotes, I have enough of them.

Comment: @Lundin: It can be useful from an optimization standpoint to allow Indeterminate Values to behave in non-deterministic fashion, but the Standard doesn't allow for non-determinism in any situation that isn't UB.  What would be helpful would be to have an annex describing various kinds of optional semantic guarantees about non-deterministic objects, and macros that would indicate which guarantees an implementation does or does not promise to uphold.  That could be especially helpful if certain patterns of aliasing yielded Indeterminate Value rather than UB.

Comment: @supercat The standard allows unspecified behavior, which isn't necessarily deterministic. "Unspecified value" sounds like unspecified behavior to me. Take padding bytes in a struct for example, their values are unspecified - and it is explicitly listed as unspecified behavior by the standard. The difference between padding bytes and indeterminate values is that padding bytes are not allowed to hold a trap representation. Thus if an indeterminate value is used and it is not a trap representation, there will be _unspecified behavior_.

Comment: @Lundin: By non-deterministic, I meant a value which remains non-deterministic *even after it's read*.  For example, if `x` is Indeterminate, but typecasts are specified as converting non-deterministic values deterministic, then after `y=x; z=(y & 1)+(y & 1); result = (int)(z+z);` the value of `result` could be anything from 0 to 4 (most likely 0 or 4, but not necessarily) but there couldn't be any *other* weird behavior.  Such a rule would allow a compiler to back-substitute `result = (x & 1)+(x & 1)+(x & 1)+(x & 1);` without being required to commit to a single value of x.

Comment: @Lundin: Back substitution can be a useful optimization technique, but it can yield unexpected results if things change when not particularly expected [something which is allowed to happen in Indeterminate-Value scenarios].  If, however, any value which could be computed in such fashion would meet an application's requirements, allowing programmers to let compilers make such substitutions without jumping the rails entirely would allow for more efficient code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard is vague as to what is or is not guaranteed if code reads an Indeterminate Value of a type which has no trap representations.  If a type has any trap representations and code attempts to read an Indeterminate Value of that type, the value read could be a trap representation, thus causing the read to invoke Undefined Behavior.  If the type does not have any trap representations, however, things are somewhat less clear.

A requirement that code cannot copy an array element unless it has initialized it, even if the type of the element would have no trap representations and even if nothing would care about the value of the copy, would reduce the efficiency with which many algorithms could be expressed.  On the other hand, given something like:

```
struct fnord { unsigned char q; ... }
struct fnord x=foo[i];
doSomething(x.q);
...
doSomething(x.q);
```

it's unclear whether a compiler would be required to ensure that the same
value would get passed to both function calls in cases where `foo[i]` held an Indeterminate Value.  Structures are not allowed to have trap representations (members of types other than `unsigned char` might, but copying an entire structure is defined behavior even when the storage underlying some members holds trap representation of their type).  On the other hand, the write to `x` might be viewed as causing `x` to hold Indeterminate Value, such that the calls to `doSomething` might receive different values.

It would be extremely helpful if the Standard specified a means by which an Indeterminate Value of a type with no trap representations could be read to yield an Unspecified Value, but I am unaware of any such specification in the Standard.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem, too and lead to the question: I couldn't lay my finger on the part(s) of the standard that are specific enough.  Would it be helpful enough to go to teh length and lobby for an inclusion in the next revision of the standard?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: The C language is, from a practical standpoint, sufficiently fragmented that the only resolution I can see is to have a standard recognize modes which would permit or deny certain forms of optimizations; in the presence of a `#pragma` specifying one mode, certain constructs which would may or may not be defined under C11 would be unambiguously defined; in another mode, they would be explicitly considered Undefined.  Behavior in the absence of either directive would be up to the implementation.  In the absence of any such directives...

Comment: ...programmers should block any change to the Standard that would regard as UB constructs which under their reading of the Standard had been defined (and useful), and compiler writers would likely block any change that would make clear that constructs which under their reading of the standard were UB (and thus did not have to be supported) had to be regarded as having defined behavior even at the expense of blocking optimizations.  Recognizing a few distinct compilation modes would avoid the need to resolve whether such constructs are defined or undefined in the absence of a directive.

Comment: there are some parts in the standard that cannot be called outright ambiguous with a clear conscious but are still open to interpretation. They are not very high in number, a handful of pragmas could do, indeed. Is there any hope that such a useful and reasonable idea will be included in the standard in our lifetime?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: Given the Committee's track record, I think it would be more likely that some other entity would formulate a useful standard than that the Committee will do so, but I don't know how to encourage anyone with enough clout to create a useful standard to make the effort.  Besides--if parts which I don't think most people would consider ambiguous in the slightest are interpreted by compiler writers in fashion contrary to their clear meaning, do you think the Committee is going to change the Standard in a way which indicates that compilers' behavior was never legitimate?

Comment: I should not answer questions that might be rhetorical but you answered mine, so: after reading the list of the WG14 members, current and past...maybe. But serious: it seems as if they are working at least at parts of it if I understood the notes in the pre-Pittsburgh papers (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/PrePittsburgh2016.tar.bz2) correctly. Maybe there's hope?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: I'm not familiar with that extension, but looking at PrePittsburgn2016.htm, there are some things I like and some I definitely don't like.  The pointer provenance rules would make some code which is presently well-defined invoke UB; while the optimizations may be useful in many cases, the proper way to accomplish that would be with directives to enable new optimizations.  With regard to uninitialized data, the behavioral model I would like to see differs from the one given: I would have each integer type modeled as being capable of holding an arbitrary set...

Comment: ...of possible integers (a possibly-unbounded set for signed types), and most operators defined as yielding the Cartesian product of the operands' possible values.  So if `x` is an uninitialized variable whose address has been taken, `(x & 1) + (x & 8)` would yield the set {0,1,8,9}.  Type conversions or casts which do not change type would be defined as selecting a value arbitrarily from the set of values something might hold, so the expression `(unsigned)((x & 1)+(x & 8))` would yield a one value chosen from the set {0,1,8,9}.  Such rules would allow many useful optimizations, but...

Comment: ...allow programmers a means of converting Indeterminate Values to Unspecified Values in a way which would be compatible existing compilers that happen to treat them identically.  What do you think of that concept?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: While making indeterminate values daemonic may make it easier for compilers to reason about them, most useful optimizations enabled by such treatment are only applicable in cases where a compiler has kept track of how values were derived and can make substitutions based upon that (e.g. if `*p` is copied to a variable which is used once immediately and once later, and neither `p` nor `*p` should have changed between the two uses, a compiler might opt not to store the read value but reread it later; the set of behaviors that might result from that substitution would coincide...

Comment: ...with one read having yielded one possible value, and the other yielding another possible value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means ARRAY_SIZE must be greater than zero.
At this level you should probably leave the optimization to the compiler. 
But if the ARRAY_SIZE is a defined constant, you can optimize by an array which its elements are the same size as your CPU registers. your array size should be an integer multiple of the size of your registers.
for more optimization you should dig into assembler outputs.